# Yarn Scheduler Load Simulator - fair-scheduler

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to do a performance analysis of my fair scheduler configuration, and I found this tool - "[YARN Scheduler Load Simulator (SLS)](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.6/hadoop-sls/SchedulerLoadSimulator.html)" which I believe can help me out. I've followed the document and setup YARN SLS to run with a sample job trace.

But I am not able to figure out how exactly to monitor scheduler behavior with this tool. It runs and shows scheduler behavior for the sample job traces I input, even without the fair-scheduler config.

If someone can point me out to how I can configure YARN SLS to use my fair-scheduler.xml, and insights on how to monitor the scheduler simulation (or better yet, what to look for), it'll be really helpful for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you look at the UI?  It shows the utilization of the cluster pretty clearly.

Comment: Like I said, I was able to start YARN SLS. and yes, I'm able to view the UI dashboard too. The thing is I haven't placed any scheduler config in Hadoop conf directory for the simulation to pick up. But it still runs the job traces I've given with respective queues. My query is,How do I configure SLS to use my fair-scheduler config? How can I analyze my scheduler queue resource usage using YARN SLS? or is it just the info available in SLS dashboard and nothing else? :)

Comment: You should just have to place it under your Hadoop conf directory.  If you configure `--output-dir` you should get all the metrics generated from the SLS run.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have compiled your own version of Hadoop. Otherwise I don't think you can get your implementation of FAIR running.

If I am not mistaken SLS is simulating the scheduler regarding the configurations that `yarn-site.xml` is providing. So that is where you should define the type of Scheduler you want to use.